# Scipy curve_fit with variable and constant arguments

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit data points with an equation using `curve_fit`, with two variable arguments and one constant. Since I would like to test different values of the constant, I would like to avoid writing it into the function.

With the  example from [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), I tried doing:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

a_test = 3

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([a_test, 0, 0], [a_test, 1., 0.5]))
```

But I get a value error because the lower and upper limits of the first arguments are equal.

Is there a way to do this without using an other library (eg lmfit)?

Comment: If it's a constant, why do you write it as a parameter in ```func``` ?

Comment: Good point, I have modified my question to explain  that  I want to be able to test different  values for  the constant.

Comment: Note that the currently accepted answer looks correct, but is incorrect, and will possibly lead to (unnoticed) incorrect results.

Comment: Is there a category or SO flag for a question that is "how can I do something that would be easy and simple to do in library X, but without using library X"?  Like, isn't the answer ("use lmfit") right there in the question?  How would you approach answering a question like "how can I robustly read in and interpret a JSON file without using any json library?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the previous answer but I think that you should do it in that way:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import *

a_test = 3

def func(x, b, c, a=a_test ):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = range(11, 17)
ydata = [a_test * np.exp(-0.8 * x) + 0.2 for x in xdata]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([0, 0], [1., 0.5]))

print(popt,pcov)
```

which leads to

```
popt = [0.79999036 0.19999999]
pcov = [[2.78472686e-11 4.44800146e-14]
 [4.44800146e-14 1.50965321e-16]]
```

Comment: I think this fails, because `a=a_test` is evaluated at compile time. So once you change `a_test`, you also need to re-compile/evaluate the function. Similar to the problem of setting a kwarg in a function to list, e.g. `a=[]`.

Comment: Test it by putting a `print(a)` function before the `return` in `func`: it will be `3`, no matter what value you change `a_test` to later and do another fit.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that returns a function that wraps your fitting function with your variable constant (yes: that is three functions):

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

def wrapperfunc(a_test):
    def tempfunc(x, b, c, a=a_test):
        return func(x, a, b, c)
    return tempfunc

a_test = 3

xdata = range(11, 17)
ydata = [a_test * np.exp(-0.8 * x) + 0.2 for x in xdata]

# Note: run `wrapperfunc`, so that the actual fitting func (`tempfunc`) is returned
popt, pcov = curve_fit(wrapperfunc(a_test), xdata, ydata, bounds=([0, 0], [1., 0.5]))

print(popt, pcov)

a_test = 4

xdata = range(11, 17)
ydata = [a_test * np.exp(-0.8 * x) + 0.2 for x in xdata]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(wrapperfunc(a_test), xdata, ydata, bounds=([0, 0], [1., 0.5]))

print(popt, pcov)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It works, but so did the solution by Panda50. I did try your suggestion of printing `a` within the function and it returned the correct value when I changed it.

Comment: @ocns I'm pretty sure it's incorrect (the accepted answer), so you may have done something else, like re-evaluating the whole function as well the second time. Anyway, I hope there are no important decisions made based on your results.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity, this sort of thing can be done easily with `lmfit` as the original question mentions.  Something like this would do:

```
import lmfit
import numpy as np
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

model = lmfit.Model(func)
params = lmfit.Parameters() 
params.add('a', value=3, vary=False)
params.add('b', value=0.5, min=0, max=1)
params.add('c', value=0.25, min=0, max=1)

# test values for a, find one with lowest chi-square
best_result, best_a, best_chisqr = None, None, 1e199
for aval in np.linspace(0, 10, 21):
    params['a'].value = aval
    result = model.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)
    if result.chisqr < best_chisqr:
       best_chisqr = result.chisqr
       best_result = result
       best_a = aval

print(f"### best value for a = {best_a:.2f}")
print(best_result.fit_report())
```

Note that attempting to freeze a variable by setting the lower and upper bound to the value will cause confusion in the statistical analysis over whether there are 2 or 3 variables in the problem.  On the other hand, looping as shown here is clearly using 2 variables at a time, but it does ignore that `a` is sort of a varying parameter.  To be most robust, you probably would want to allow `a` to vary.

The "burden" of using `lmfit` is that one would have to run "pip install lmfit", which could take several seconds -- perhaps even as long as it took you to read this message.